# CakePHP if session doesn't exist render a different layout and view

Tags: php, cakephp

I am building a site that requires a simple authentication system to sit on top of my site so that only people with the password can access it. This is different to users and the authentication component as it's just to prevent access unless you're supposed to.

The reason is I have a preview site for a client and I only want them to be able to access it but can't use the in-built authentication as they need to see both logged in and logged out states hence using a custom simple authentication (note this doesn't need to be secure).

I have a working system in place and to prevent access I do a check in the AppController so that all requests first check if my session exists:

```
public function beforeRender()
{
    if ($this->Session->check('client') != true)
    {
        $this->layout = 'client_login'; 
        $this->render = 'pages/client_login';
    }
}
```

**The layout bit works fine** so it understands the session, but it doesn't show my client login view which has a simple login form on it so it's not doing the render properly. Any ideas why not? And any better ideas to show the layout and view for all actions across the site if that session does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'render' is a function, not a property. So your code should probably be:

```
$this->render('pages/client_login');
```

edit: by the way, this code can't be placed in the beforeRender() callback, because this would lead to an infinite loop (render() raises beforeRender()).

beforeFilter() would certainly be a better place.

```
function beforeFilter()
{
    if ($this->Session->check('client') != true)
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->layout = 'client_login';
        $this->render('/pages/client_login');
    }
}
```

### EDIT

Like explained in my comments, the explicit call to render() in the PagesController->display() method prevents what you want to do to work when you are on an URL that uses the PagesController.

Rethinking a bit about your needs, I see two solutions.

If you need a simple way to fully protect your website temporarely, without modifying your application code, you could use Apache to protect the access through the .htaccess. A basic authentication or maybe a filter on IP or domain could maybe do the trick in your case. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html

If you want to use Cake because you already have your custom authentication system working that fill the Session, you could use the Auth component just to grant or deny access. In your AppController, you could have something like:

```
function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->Auth->loginAction = '/pages/client_login';

    if($this->Session->check('client'))
    {
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
    }
}
```

Comment: That works but the default page is also loading... I tried using exit() after the code but that just breaks the app. How do I stop it from showing everything else?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the default page is also loading' ? Do you mean that you see two mixed views ?...

Comment: Yes I get the other view showing as well! The idea is that this code should overwrite the other actions layout and view if that session is not present.

Comment: This is strange if you see the view of the url action and the content of your client_login view. AFAIK, Cake can only render one view at a time. Are you sure the rest of the HTML you get is not part of the client_login layout ? Or contained in a element called by your layout or your client_login view ?

Comment: 100% sure. The rest of the HTML is inside `/pages/home.ctp` so it's still calling the original view after the preview one we're adding because of their being no session.

Comment: OK. Strange, I just tested a similar code (on Cake 1.3.7) and I only get the content of my pages/test.ctp. Just an idea, there is also a controller variable called $autoRender. What happens if you set it to false ? (I'll edit the code to reflect that)

Comment: I just noticed that it is a special case with the PagesController, probably because the method render() is called explicitely in the PagesController->display() method. I'll try to find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Session->read('client')) {
   //client session exists
}
else {
   //client session does not exist
}

Comment: Hi the session part work fine as it renders the layout! Just not the view!

Answer (score 0):

For this cases, I usually use Basic http Authentication
[Protecting content with basic authentication](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html#basicconfig)

You add the following directives in .htaccess that sits int the directory above your app folder (read [1](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html#basicconfig) for more options)

```
AuthUserFile    /path/to/your/folder/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile   /dev/null
AuthName    Administration
AuthType    Basic
```

Create a .htpasswd file in the same directory with login/password couples, use the tool below

http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/